# Recently PHPMAILER stops sending mail

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have searched a lot but not succeed to find the solution after that i am asking question here.

I am using phpmailer on many websites to send mail to admin's email address. The following code was working great in past days but recently i got errors in some websites and some websites don't show any error and print that       " Mail sent " but i got no email.

Here is my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

        try {
          $mail->Host       = "localhost"; // SMTP server
          $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
          $mail->AddAddress('ADMIN_ADDRESS');
          $mail->SetFrom($_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['lname'] . ', ' . $_REQUEST['fname']);
          $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form';
          $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
          $mail->MsgHTML($body);
          $mail->Send();
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
          echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
        }
```

**Notice**: I am facing this problem on live websites. Thanks

Comment: You're using the default 'mail' transport here, so the most likey explanation is that your local mail server has a problem - check your mail server logs.

Comment: Thanks i will check the server logs

Answer (score 0):

Synchro's comment is spot-on.  If you have access to the local MTA on the server, you should check its logs, and these will show you 1) whether or not the MTA is receiving the messages that your application is handing-off to it through PHPMailer, and 2) what is happening when the MTA attempts to deliver these messages to the recipients' MX's.

If accessing the local MTA's logs is not possible, then you might want to change your PHP script to use PHPMailer to send outgoing messages through a remote SMTP server that you have credentials for, and preferably one that allows you to access logs showing what happens with messages that are relayed through it.  See [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) of how to use PHPMailer to send through a remote SMTP server (in this case, smtp.gmail.com).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will ask the client to check its MTA on his server.